# Knockout Component Taking long Time to render

Tags: knockout.js

I have a long List of LogEntries getting render by knouckout component.I have this component structure.

```
--<full-logentry> inside I render three other component
<task-logentry> inside three type of component for task log entry</task-logentrty>
<project-logentry>5 components of  project log entry type </project-logentry>
<field-logentry></field-logentry>
</full-logentry>


render list like this 
Adam has added the role "" .. - a month ago
Adam has added the role "" .. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to Admin. - a month ago
Adam has added the role "" .. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to david. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to test.user23. - a month ago
 Adam has approved. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to him/herself. - a month ago
 Adam has declined. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to him/herself. - a month ago
Adam has removed "Admin" .. - a month ago
Adam has removed "david" .. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to him/herself. - a month ago
 Adam has approved. - a month ago
 Adam has reversed his decision. - a month ago
 Adam has approved. - a month ago
 Adam has reversed his decision. - a month ago
Adam assigned the task to him/herself. - a month ago
Adam has removed "test.user23" .. - a month ago
```

is there is anyother way to improve the speed ,performance ,is it because large set of data, to much components .

Comment: There's no way to tell without seeing all of your code.

Comment: Try turning on deferred updates: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html